# Redux array state is not updating when dispatching from useEffect hook

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I am trying to update a state in react-redux using hooks, on a button click.

When a button is clicked, it updated the ordersArray and I need to update that array in redux state.

Currently I am using below code, and my state array remains same without any change.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!_.isEmpty(tempOrders)) {
      //   console.log('tempOrderstempOrders', tempOrders);
      dispatch(storeCartOrders(tempOrders));
    }
  }, [dispatch, tempOrders]);
```

cartOrderSlice.js

```
import {createSlice, createAsyncThunk} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'cartOrder',
  initialState: {
    cartOrders: [],
  },
  reducers: {
    // Redux Toolkit allows us to write "mutating" logic in reducers. It
    // doesn't actually mutate the state because it uses the immer library,
    // which detects changes to a "draft state" and produces a brand new
    // immutable state based off those changes
    storeCartOrders: (state, action) => {
      console.log('action.payload', action.payload) // <-- this payload always has old values 
      state.cartOrders = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const {storeCartOrders} = slice.actions;

export default slice.reducer;
```

- Below `useEffect` is called when button is clicked
- Below useEffect will `setTempOrders` which in turn will call the `useEffect` hook with `dispath` function

  ```
    useEffect(() => {
  const updateOrders = async () => {
          let rows = [...tempOrders];
    if (currentItemValues) {
            const currentItemIndex = rows.findIndex(
              (row) => row.id === currentItemValues.id,
            ); 
        if (currentItemIndex >= 0) {
          if (currentItemValues.quantity === 0) {
            rows.splice(currentItemIndex, 1);
          } else {
            rows[currentItemIndex]['quantity'] = currentItemValues.quantity;

          }
        }
      }
      // console.log('rowsrowsrows', rows);
     // rows[currentItemIndex]['quantity'] is not being changed at all. 
    // and that's why storage and setTempOrders won't change the data. 
       setTempOrders(rows);
      await setLocalCartItems('cart', rows);
    };

    if (!_.isEmpty(tempOrders)) {
      updateOrders();
    }
  }, [currentItemValues, toggle]);
  ```

Please let me know if you need to show more code.
Your help is much appreciated! Thanks

**currentItemValues**
[image]

Sometimes it gives error like :

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'quantity' of object '#<Object>'
```

Comment: can you show your button click code? if you have a button click, why do you need to use useEffect when you can just call the dispatch on click?

Comment: I have updated question and title, its being called from useEffect. sorry for confusion.

Comment: what's the current value before you call setTempOrders(rows)?

Comment: the value of currentItemValues.

Comment: I updated the question. actually I am realizing it may be not related to dispatch function not updating state. its more of an array not updating the value rows[currentItemIndex]['quantity'] = currentItemValues.quantity; pls look at image and know that quantity came as 3 but it was not changed after the rows update.

Comment: If I comment the dispatch function then rows array will get updated without any problem. so not sure where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

you have an array for object, so you need to do the following

```
rows[currentItemIndex].quantity = currentItemValues.quantity;
```